# Change or hide a custom action from the standard page in MS D365 Business Central, which is added via another custom extension

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al, cal, businesscentral

Hope you all are doing well! I recently encountered a new requirement on how to change the name of a custom action and also hide a custom action from the standard page (Sales Order) in MS D365 Business Central, which is added via another custom extension.

No doubt, one can do so by using a page extension. Suppose one doesn’t have access to the code or symbols from that custom extension. In such a case, how can one simply change the caption of a custom action and also hide a custom action by building and deploying a new extension?

Can anyone please confirm if this is possible or not? Thanks for reading.

I'm seeking guidance on whether it's possible to achieve this without access to the code or symbols from the custom extension.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there afaik at the moment (v23) it is not possible to change the behaviour of the custom action if you can't add the custom extension to your dependencies due to the lack of access to the symbols, so you can't change the name of a custom action and you can't hide a custom action.

**Without development**

To hide fields or actions you can use the **Personalize** feature.

[image: personalize user]

If you want to hide fields/actions for multiple users, navigate to the *Profiles (Roles)* page, select a Profile, e.g. *BUSINESS MANAGER* and click on the *Customize pages* action on the *Profile (Role)* page card.

[image: personalize profile]

Read on:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/ui-personalization-user
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/ui-personalization-manage

**With development**

Hide field/action via *Page Extension*:

```
actions
{
    modify(StackOverflow)
    {
        Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Change the caption of the custom action via *Page Extension* (would not recommend this):

```
actions
{
    modify(StackOverflow)
    {
        Caption = 'Overflow Action';
    }
}
```

In MS Learn you will find the section [Translating other extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-work-with-translation-files#translating-other-extensions), which describes how you can translate the captions of other extensions via **.xlf** (XLIFF) files without having to create new page extension objects. This is the recommended way if you want to translate apps into several languages.